# Reload JavaScript without page reload

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP page and I reload one div when filters are used or when a page of pagination is clicked. I have a problem with the pagination because **it works only for the first time**. I think I need to reload the pagination script when the div's content changes without the page reloading.

This is the function I need to reuse:

```
   $('li.page').on('click', function() {
        var clicked = $(this).find('a').text();
        var paginations = $('ul.pagination');
        var previous = paginations.find('li.page.active');
        previous.removeClass('active');
        var links = paginations.find('li.page');
        links.each(function() {
            if ($(this).find('a').text() == clicked) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
        $('#page').text(clicked);
        showItems();
        //location.reload(); //aktualizuje celou stránku
    });
```

The other function that updates the div's content:

```
    function showItems() {
         var nazevkat = document.getElementById("nazevkat").innerHTML;
         var kategorie = document.getElementById("kategorie").innerHTML;
         var podkategorie = document.getElementById("podkategorie").innerHTML;
         var razeni = document.getElementById("razeni").value;    
         vyhledavani = document.getElementById("vyhledavani").innerHTML;
         vyhledavani = vyhledavani.replace(/ /gi, "+");    
         var start = document.getElementById("start-interval-2").value;
         var end = document.getElementById("end-interval-2").value;

       var vyrobce = $('#vyrobci :checked');
       var vyrobci = "";
       for (var i = 0; i < vyrobce.length; i++) {
              vyrobci += vyrobce[i].value + "+";
        }
        vyrobci = vyrobci.substring(0, vyrobci.length - 1);

        var dostupnosti = $('#dostupnosti :checked');
        var dostupnost = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < dostupnosti.length; i++) {
            dostupnost += dostupnosti[i].value + "+";
        }
        dostupnost = dostupnost.substring(0, dostupnost.length - 1);   
        var page = document.getElementById("page").innerHTML;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("page-content-items").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };

        var newUrl = getCutURL(kategorie, podkategorie, razeni, vyhledavani, start, end, vyrobci, dostupnost, nazevkat, page);
        history.pushState('', 'Alter URL', newUrl.replace("getItems", "produkty"));

        var url = getURL(kategorie, podkategorie, razeni, vyhledavani, start, end, vyrobci, dostupnost, "", page);
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();    
    }
```

Comment: I think this maybe helped jQuery.get("./js/filters.js");

Comment: But I also had to add a script into a php function that echo's the content. "echo '<script>var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src = "./js/filters.js";
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);</script>';"

Comment: But my page links kinda flickers when I hover over them and sometimes I have to double click for them to work. ---> it happens because the scripts in the div somehow reload over and over again even if I do nothing.

Comment: I'm desperate. Previous solution made other things not working so I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is solve your problem

```
$.fn.myClick= function (callback) {
        $(document).on('click', $(this).selector, function(event) { // this (jQuery) method is working
            callback($(this));
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        return $;
    };

$('li.page').myClick(function($this){
    var clicked = $this.find('a').text();
        var paginations = $('ul.pagination');
        var previous = paginations.find('li.page.active');
        previous.removeClass('active');
        var links = paginations.find('li.page');
        links.each(function() {
            if ($this.find('a').text() == clicked) {
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
        });
        $('#page').text(clicked);
        showItems();
        //location.reload(); //aktualizuje celou stránku
});
```

for using heavenPG, you need to read documentation
https://github.com/rachmanzz/heavenPG

#### first: define heavenPG Construct

```
var pagination = heavenPG({
id : 'ul.pagination',
total:10, // total page
current:3, // current page active
onclick:function(page){
    console.log('current page :'+page); // page number clicked
}
});
pagination.execute();
```

#### Make Paginition List (using bootstrap component L http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination )

```
<ul class="pagination">
</ul>
```

and don't forget to load jQuery and boostrap libary

example : http://rachmanzz.github.io/heavenPG/

Comment: where exactly shoud I define it? it doesn't work when I put it in a script tag on the page

Comment: I would rather solve my current problem with the javascript working only for the first time

Answer (score 0):

Changing the trigger works perfectly!

```
    $('.page-content').on('click', 'li.page', function() {
        var clicked = $(this).find('a').text();
        var paginations = $('ul.pagination');
        var previous = paginations.find('li.page.active');
        previous.removeClass('active');
        var links = paginations.find('li.page');
        links.each(function() {
            if ($(this).find('a').text() == clicked) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
        $('#page').text(clicked);
        showItems();
    });
```